# LTE eNB stack conversion from Uu interface to S1 interface

Tags: lte

There are two separate stacks at BBU/eNB as shown in the figure. One serving with Uu interface and other with S1 interface.

My question is, when a packet comes from MME to eNB, will this packet(coming from MME to eNB) be encapsulated with RRC header/PDCP header etc? or is there any mapping mechanism maintained?

[image]